# MYSQl selecting data from different tables and doing the average

Tags: mysql

Hi I am trying to select the data from different tables in MYSQL and trying to the average all the data So can one tell me how to do that.

This is Query.

```
SELECT 
  Q7,
  Q8 
FROM
  day1 
WHERE day1.user = 'test' 
UNION
SELECT 
  Q7,
  Q8 
FROM
  day2 
WHERE day2.user = 'test'
```

This is my Query output

```
    Q7  Q8
    34  49
    51  50
    46  40
    55  29
    52  58
    30  37
    55  0
    46  0
    32  0
    31  0
    38  0
    49  0
```

I would Like take the average of the output obtained.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT 
  AVG(Q7),
  AVG(Q8) 
FROM
  (SELECT 
    Q7,
    Q8 
  FROM
    day1 
  WHERE day1.user = 'test' 
  UNION
  SELECT 
    Q7,
    Q8 
  FROM
    day2 
  WHERE day2.user = 'test')
```

Comment: It was stating that "Every derived table must have its own alias"

Answer (score 0):

```
  SELECT 
  AVG(Q7),
  AVG(Q8) 
FROM
  day1 
WHERE day1.user = 'test' 
UNION
SELECT 
  Q7,
  Q8 
FROM
  day2 
WHERE day2.user = 'test'
```